# Tab-like keyboard navigation with plus sign in HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, telerik, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a .NET WebForms page with Telerik UI for ASP.NET AJAX with an HTML form.

- The tab key navigates through fields on the form as expected. If the field has default contents, they are selected on focus to make it easier to change.
- The plus sign key also navigates through the fields via some custom javascript (see below) on the form; however, when navigating with the plus sign into a field with a default value, the default value is not highlighted on first focus right after page load. If I plus back into it again for a second time after page load, though, the default contents are highlighted as expected.

What do I need to tweak to cause existing default contents of a field to be highlighted on focus with the plus sign key?

```
function handlePlusKey(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 107) {
        var control = this;
        var found = false;
        $(tabTypes).each(function (i) {
            if (this.className.indexOf('rtsLink') == -1
                    && this.id.indexOf('InitInsertButton') == -1
                    && this.title != "Click here to sort"
                    && this.tabIndex > -1
                    && $(this).is(":visible")
                    && !$(this).is(":disabled"))
                if (this == control) {
                    found = true;
                }
                else if (found) {
                    this.focus();
                    found = false;
                }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it do this on every browser? This could be a bug in the browser you're using.

Comment: Seems to occur, albeit somewhat intermittently, in up-to-date stable channels of Chrome, Firefox, and IE on Windows 10.

Comment: It may have something to do with the plus key trying to input an actual value on the previous field before tabbing to the next, thus the value in the new one never gets selected. Just a guess, though.

Comment: Thanks, @BrandonMiller . I discovered that the plus sign key navigation is custom js, so I just heavily revamped the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the selection manually

```
inputElement.focus();
inputElement.setSelectionRange(0, inputElement.value.length);
```

Change `inputElelemnt` to the element that needs to be highlighted. In most cases this would be `event.target`, I think it's `control` in your case.